# High Entropy Unique ID for Filenames

Tags: php

I would like to create a unique ID (filename) for some of my files and would like to do so with minimal concern. My original plan was to use a `base64` encoded string of random bytes but this will not work because `/` is a valid `base64` character.

The function I currently use looks like this:

```
static function uniqueID(){
    return base64_encode(random_bytes(16));
}
```

How could I go about generating a high entropy unique ID that will always be a certain length and contain only characters that are valid in filenames?

Note: I do not wish to use a solution that accomplishes this with `str_replace()`.

Edit: I appreciate the responses so far.This is one solution Ive explored locally but I am not sure how to calculate how much entropy I lose when compared to `uniqueID()`.

```
public static function uniqueFilename(){
    return bin2hex(random_bytes(12));
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: 12 bytes = 96 bits. If you generated a random 96-bit value and then tried to _intentionally_ brute-force guess a collision you'd need to build a Dyson sphere around the sun to power the computer and then wait a few centuries. Just use the random bytes.

Comment: 96 bits is like concatenating 3x 32bit numbers together, the number of possibilities is: 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As User: [Sammitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064767/sammitch) stated,

> 12 bytes = 96 bits. If you generated a random 96-bit value and then
> tried to intentionally brute-force guess a collision you'd need to
> build a Dyson sphere around the sun to power the computer and then
> wait a few centuries. Just use the random bytes.
>
> 96 bits is like
> concatenating 3x 32bit numbers together, the number of possibilities
> is: 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336

Knowing this we can justify using the following function when `$n >= 12`.

```
public static function uniqueFilename($n = 12){
    return bin2hex(random_bytes($n));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Ramsey's UUID: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid .
We use it in production and it does the job.

Comment: I will explore this as a solution. Thanks for the response